# How to show temporal difference methods converge to MLE?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, convergence, temporal-difference-methods

In chapter 6 of [Sutton and Barto](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/10-703/textbook/BartoSutton.pdf) (p. 128), they claim temporal difference converges to the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE). How can this be shown formally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The convergence and optimality proofs of (linear) temporal-difference methods (under batch training, so not online learning) can be found in the paper [Learning to predict by the methods of temporal differences](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF00115009.pdf) (1988) by Richard Sutton, specifically section 4 (p. 23). In this paper, Sutton uses a different notation than the notation used in the famous book [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/10-703/textbook/BartoSutton.pdf) (2nd ed.), by Sutton and Barto, so I suggest you get familiar with the notation before attempting to understand the theorem and the proof. For example, Sutton uses letters such as $i$ and $j$ to denote *states* (rather than $s$), $z$ to denote (scalar) *outcomes* and $x$ to denote (vector) *observations* (see section 3.2 for example of the usage of this notation).

In the paper [The Convergence of TD($\lambda$) for General $\lambda$](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1022632907294.pdf) (1992), Peter Dayan, apart from recapitulating the convergence proof provided by Sutton, he also shows the convergence properties of TD($\lambda$) and he extends Watkins' Q-learning convergence theorem, whose sketch is presented in his PhD thesis [Learning from Delayed Rewards](https://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/chrisw/new_thesis.pdf) (1989), and defined in detail in [Technical Note: Q-learning](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~dayan/papers/cjch.pdf) (1992), by Dayan and Watkins, to provide the first strongest guarantee or convergence proof for TD(0).

There is much more research work on the convergence properties of TD methods, such as Q-learning and SARSA. For example, in the paper [On the Convergence of Stochastic Iterative Dynamic Programming Algorithms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.4499&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1994), where Q-learning is presented as a stochastic form of dynamic programming methods, the authors provide a proof of convergence for Q-learning by making direct use of [stochastic approximation theory](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~liam/teaching/compstat-spr14/lauren-notes.pdf). See also [Convergence of Q-learning: a simple proof](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~mtjspaan/readingGroup/ProofQlearning.pdf) by Francisco S. Melo. In the paper [Convergence Results for Single-Step On-Policy Reinforcement-Learning Algorithms](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1007678930559.pdf), the authors provide a proof of the convergence properties of on-line temporal difference methods (e.g. SARSA).

Comment: Notes by Francisco S. Melo are deeply inspired by the paper On the Convergence of Stochastic Iterative Dynamic Programming Algorithms (1994) I think ! Nothing about "Likelihood" however?

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher I'm not sure whether I fully read the 1994 paper, and, if I did, it was already a few years ago, so I don't remember the details and I can't confirm that's the case. I had read Melo's paper though. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out. Regarding your question, now, I don't remember the details of the proofs  to tell you if they mention anything about the "convergence to the MLE". I would need to read them again. Let me know if you figure out anything about this issue.

Comment: By the way, I have seen an article saying on your blog MDP are PO-MDP. Reciprocally, PO-MDP can be transformed into MDP but with larger spaces! see p. 96 from Adaptive Markov Control Processes - O. Hernandez Lerma

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher Yes! Are you referring to Belief MDPs? Basically, you treat belief states as the states.