# Is there a simple proof of the convergence of TD(0)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, proofs, convergence, temporal-difference-methods

Does anybody know a simple proof of the convergence of the TD(0) value function prediction algorithm?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no *very* simple proof of the convergence of temporal-difference algorithms. The proofs of convergence of TD algorithms are often based on [stochastic approximation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation) (given that e.g. [Q-learning can be viewed as a stochastic process](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/764-convergence-of-stochastic-iterative-dynamic-programming-algorithms.pdf)) and the work by [Robbins and Monro](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Robbins-MonroStochasticApproximation.html) (in fact, the Robbins-Monro conditions are usually assumed in the theorems and proofs).

The proofs of convergence of Q-learning (a TD(0) algorithm) and SARSA (another TD(0) algorithm), when the value functions are represented in tabular form (as opposed to being approximated with e.g. a neural network), can be found in different research papers.

For example, the **proof of convergence of tabular Q-learning** can be found in the paper [Convergence of Stochastic Iterative Dynamic Programming Algorithms](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/764-convergence-of-stochastic-iterative-dynamic-programming-algorithms.pdf) (1994) by Tommi Jaakkola et al. The **proof of convergence of tabular SARSA** can be found in the paper [Convergence Results for Single-Step On-Policy Reinforcement-Learning Algorithms](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1007678930559.pdf) (2000) by Satinder Singh et al.

See also [How to show temporal difference methods converge to MLE?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/13973/2444).